# How do I stop my HDMI going off

Tags: raspbian-stretch, hdmi, pi-3b+

for some reason, after a while the screen connected to my RPI 3B+ goes off, and stays off, until I unplug it and plug it back in again.  I only run in console mode, and running alt+F[1-4] does nothing, neither does pressing any key, but unplugging and plugging back in the HDMI is the only sure way to bring it back.

I use an HDMI=>SVGA connector, then connect to an SVGA monitor, and disconnecting at the SVGA side has no effect.

I've added

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

to /boot/config.txt

and I've added

```
consoleblank=0
```

to /boot/cmdline.txt

but still after a while the screen goes off, and won't come back until I unplug it.

Anyone have any ideas?